# Best way to share the state between components in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've currently set up the a React context to share the state and the current version looks like the following:

**QueryContext.js**

```js
import { createContext } from "react";

const queryContext = createContext({
    query: "",
    setQuery: (value) => {},
});

export default queryContext;
```

**App.js**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import QueryContext from "./contexts/QueryContext";

import Header from "./Header";
import Nav from "./Nav";
import Main from "./Main";
import Footer from "./Footer";

const App = () => {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

    return (
        <>
            <QueryContext.Provider value={{ query, setQuery }}>
                <Header />
            </QueryContext.Provider>
                <Nav />
            <QueryContext.Provider value={{ query, setQuery }}>
                <Main />
            </QueryContext.Provider>
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Since `Nav` is placed between `Header` and `Main`, there was no choice but wrapping both with separate providers.

Should I just use props instead of context like the following?

**App.js**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Header from "./Header";
import Nav from "./Nav";
import Main from "./Main";
import Footer from "./Footer";

const App = () => {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

    return (
        <>
            <Header value={{ query, setQuery }} />
            <Nav />
            <Main value={{ query, setQuery }} />
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context is technology which allows developers to pass data through a lot of levels of application tree. The first thing to remember here - if something is global, it should probably be placed in context and accessed from anywhere with level lower. Passing data through several levels using properties will probably be bad practice - code quality will decrease along with performance, probably.

I assume, that in your case it is better to make context (you already did - `QueryContext`) and place it as higher as allowed:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import QueryContext from "./contexts/QueryContext";

import Header from "./Header";
import Nav from "./Nav";
import Main from "./Main";
import Footer from "./Footer";

const App = () => {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

    return (
        <QueryContext.Provider value={{ query, setQuery }}>
            <Header />
            <Nav />
            <Main />
            <Footer />
        </QueryContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

All components which require data from `QueryContext` could extract it via `useContext(QueryContext)`. As bonus against props way here - you are allowed to place `Header` and `Main` components as deep as you want, they will still have access to context.

In my opinion, the best solution here is to implement 2 components for each working with query: 1-st one will work with props, the 2-nd one with context, *but you probably dont need it as long as it could be overengineering*. Here is the example:

```
interface Props {
  query: string;
  setQuery: (value: string) => void;
}

function Header(props: Props) {
  return (...);
}

function HeaderConnected() {
  const {query, setQuery} = useContext(QueryContext);

  return <Header query={query} setQuery={setQuery}/>
}
```

This component separation method provides developer 2 flexible ways of using component. You could do the same with components, attached to Redux storage - writing their pure variant along with "connected" to storage.

My remarks for your code here:

1. In your case, there is no need to create several context providers placed on the same level with same value. Make it single and move to upper level.
2. In my opinion, there is no need to make such prop as `value` containing query and its setter. This is rather unclear, what `value` is and seems that these values should be extracted from some global scope (context), but it depends on task context.